# Sublime Text Regex Replace and Append

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

Can someone please help me with a regular expression.

I'm having trouble with even the start as I'm a regex absolute beginner and the tutorials aren't really helping as I'm not understanding it.

I've got a large amount of files with things like 'products.htmlcar' or 'products.htmlcar_paper' or 'products.htmlhome-decorative_air_freshener'

I'm trying to remove all instances in all my files of the words "'products.html" and replace them with just the text at the end of it and append html to it before the ending " ' "  for example 'products.htmlcar' becomes 'car.html' or 'products.htmlhome-decorative_air_freshener' becomes 'home-decorative_air_freshener.html'

I have tried to do a few of the things I checked out like

```
\^'products.html
```

but sublime text is not searching for this correctly. I don't know whether my syntax is incorrect or something but it's really confusing me.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Find: products\.html(.*?)'
Replace: $1.html'
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Use this if your strings are

```
products.htmlcar
products.htmlcar_paper
products.htmlhome-decorative_air-freshener
```

```regex
^products.html
```

if your strings have ' a

```regex
^'products.html
```